# How to prepend after 2nd 'li' in a list jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list tag with two li in it already. I want to prepend after 2nd li in this list

```
<ul class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-ext">
  <li><a href="#" onclick='showconfirmation(this,"dashboard")'>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick='showconfirmation(this,"setuppage")'>Setup IVR</a></li>
  <!-- <li>comes here</li> -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()`, as prepend() insert content to the beginning of element always.

Answer (score 1):

Use append instead.

```
$('.breadcrumb').append('<li>text</li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/), here is a working snippet:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.breadcrumb').append('<li><a href="#">new item</a></li>');
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-ext">
  <li><a href="#" onclick='showconfirmation(this,"dashboard")'>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick='showconfirmation(this,"setuppage")'>Setup IVR</a></li>
  <!-- <li>comes here</li> -->
</ul>
```